# Windows slideshow with tasks

Tags: windows, slideshow, task, monitor

Hi and thanks before hand.
At my restaurant we keep all the menu items in a monitor plugged to a Windows 7 machine, but customers usually ask for another menu to be shown so we have to manually switch the applications. Is there some way to make a slideshow-wise install to switch between applications (something like and Automatic Timed ALT + TAB)?

Answer (score 0):

Have them on your website, allow customers to browse the website.